# Any idea on how to use woocommerce api from WordPress and integrate it in your flutter App?

Tags: dart, flutter

Any idea on how to use woocommerce api from WordPress and integrate it in your flutter App?
pls guys I really need answer to this.
thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for someone to do your research for you? Have you tried a few web searches?

Answer (score 1):

This might help: https://pub.dev/packages/woosignal

It's a WooCommerce package for Flutter apps, it'll return the object models back too.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this page, which has pretty detailed steps on how to set up the API:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/

Then this page, which shows you how to make API calls in Flutter:
https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: Perhaps you could make a short summary of the provided links to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you would want a complete plug and play Woocommerce Sdk that handles authentication, products, customer, shipping etc for you, you can use the Woo Commerce SDK library for flutter at https://pub.dev/packages/woocommerce

```
Woocommerce myWoocommerce = WooCommerce(baseUrl: yourBaseUrl, consumerKey: yourConsumerKey, consumerSecret: consumerSecret);
```

Then simply register your new customer.

```
WooCustomer newCustomer = WooCustomer(id: id, firstName:firstName, etc);
myWoocommerce.createCustomer(newCustomer); //Returns the created Woocommerce customer.
```

Other examples.

```
myWooCommerce.fetchLoggedInUser() // returns the logged in user.
myWoocommerce.addToCart(quantity, id, [variations]);

myWooCommerce.createOrder(WooOrderPayload order); // etc
```